# Linux Bourne shell - directory writable check is always returning as "Not Writable"

Tags: linux, shell

This function is ALWAYS returning True when it comes to testing if the directory is NOT writable. Can anyone please explain to me why? It is only the "Is the directory writable" (so far) that is failing. But I wanted to include the entire function to give more detail about what is going on beforehand.

This function accepts a "before" and "after" string to rename a file and/or directory by replacing all spaces with dashes. I was just going to use the "rename" function, but there was a pre-built skeleton script that I needed to follow.

Updated scipt:

```
    my_rename()
    {
        echo "Trying: myrename $1 $2"

        # implement this function to my_rename $1 to $2
        # The following error checking must happen:

        # 1. check if the directory where $1 resided is writeable, if not then report an error
        # Is it a directory or a file
        if [ -d $1 ]
        then
            dnam=$1
            ftyp=$"dir"
        else
            # It's a file. Let's get the dirname
            dnam=$(dirname $1)\"
            ftyp=$"file"
        fi

        echo "dnam $dnam"

        # Is the directory writable
        errcd=0
        if [ ! -w "$dnam" ]
        then
            # Not writable. Show an error.
            echo "Directory $dnam is not writable by $(whoami)"
            errcd=1
        fi

        # 2. check if "$2" exists -if it does report and error and don't do the mv command
        if [ "$errcd" -eq 0 ] && ([ -f $2 ] || [ -d $2 ])
        then
            if [ $ftyp = "file" ]
            then
                echo "File $2 already exists"
            else
                echo "Directory $2 already exists"
            fi
            errcd=1
        fi

        # 3. check the status of the mv command and report any errors
        if [ "$errcd" -eq 0 -a -e $2 ]
        then
            exec "mv -f $1 $2"
            if [ $? -gt 0 ]
            then
                echo "Command failed: myrename $1 $2"
            fi
        fi
    }


    bryan@bryan-VirtualBox:~/renametest$ ./script3.sh -f ~/renametest
    Trying: myrename "/home/bryan/renametest/1 2" "/home/bryan/renametest/1-2"
    dnam "/home/bryan/renametest"
    Directory "/home/bryan/renametest" is not writable by bryan

    drwxr-xr-x  3 bryan bryan  4096 2013-04-03 17:10 renametest
```

Comment: Which shell exactly are you using?  Maybe -w doesn't do what you want it to do?

Comment: Well, I use Ubuntu 10.10. So, bash is default there (I think). But the person I'm doing this for is using SunOS 5.9 and Korn shell.

Comment: You've got a LOT of syntax issues there. For example `if $ftyp="file"` should be `if [ $ftyp = "file" ]` and `if $? > 0` should be `if [ $? -gt 0 ]`. (And consider this: `if [ "$errcd" -eq 0 -a ( -f $2 -o -d $2 ) ]` or maybe just `if [ "$errcd" -eq 0 -a -e $2 ]` ) You should also think about the value in $ftyp and why it doesn't tell you anything about $2.

Comment: @William: Thank you for pointing those out. I'm sure it's obvious, but yeah, I'm still pretty new at this. I've made the 3 changes that you mentioned (opting for [ "$errcd" -eq 0 -a -e $2 ] in that either/or case. But the original problem still remains. The -w test is still always returning not writable. Also, doesn't the ([ -f $2 ] || [ -d $2 ]) test tell me if $2 exists and is either a file or a directory? Or did I misunderstand that as well?

Comment: hmmm ... I think I know what you might be getting at with $2 ... since we're already returning known files or directories, why test if it's a file or directory? If that's the case, how would I just test to see if the "to" ($2) already exists?

Comment: Doing a "man test" shows: -w FILE, FILE exists and write permission is granted.

Comment: Can you create a very small script that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Re: the -w problem, look upstream. If the first argument is a directory dnam is set to it, but if it is not a directory _or does not exist_, you do this: `dnam=$(dirname $1)\"` (That escaped " at the end suggests what's wrong.) The output sample you show has either been edited, or, as the escaped " suggests, you passed those values into the function with quotation marks as part of the value - bad idea and I can pretty much guarantee you the file/directory names on the system do not include quotes. Looks like this problem is at the point you call this function, not in the function.

Comment: I do pass them with the quotes surrounding them. But only because they contain spaces. Should I remove the start and end quotes after the function is called? I don't think I can call the function with the spaces, because that would totally throw off passing the startname ($1 with the spaces) and endname ($2 with the spaces changed to dashes).

Comment: Removed the begin and end quotes. The -w test works great! Now, everything works great up until the point of: exec "mv -f $1 $2". And I just found out why ... I have to write some kind of "mv directorytree function" or something. I'm not quite sure what to do yet. But thanks everyone for all the help so far. Expect another question or two soon.

Answer (score 0):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

Re: the -w problem, look upstream. If the first argument is a directory dnam is set to it, but if it is not a directory or does not exist, you do this: dnam=$(dirname $1)\" (That escaped " at the end suggests what's wrong.) The output sample you show has either been edited, or, as the escaped " suggests, you passed those values into the function with quotation marks as part of the value - bad idea and I can pretty much guarantee you the file/directory names on the system do not include quotes. Looks like this problem is at the point you call this function, not in the function. –  William